# Issue deploying to elastic beanstalk "50npm.sh failed"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, npm, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm having an issue deploying some code to one of my environments.

```
Creating application version archive "app-aa68e-170213_103330".
Uploading PAS-API/app-aa68e-170213_103330.zip to S3. This may take a while.
Upload Complete.
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
ERROR: Failed to run npm install. Snapshot logs for more details.   
ERROR: [Instance: i-0ee97a5c7bcab8d51] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)..."/opt/elasticbeanstalk/containerfiles/ebnode.py", line 180, in npm_install
    raise e
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/opt/elasticbeanstalk/node-install/node-v4.4.6-linux-x64/bin/npm', '--production', 'install']' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/50npm.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances. Summary: [Successful: 0, Failed: 1].
ERROR: Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-0ee97a5c7bcab8d51'. Aborting the operation.
```

It seems that the deployment is failing when `npm install` is running on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I checked the `package.json` it seemed some of the deps were added as a tarball instead of a version number, meaning that when it installed and saved it looked like this:

```
"basic-auth": "https://registry.npmjs.org/basic-auth/-/basic-auth-1.0.4.tgz"
```

Rather than

```
"basic-auth": "^1.1.0",
```

This was failing on `npm install` on the eb instance, it looks like it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If it was OK before and you didn't change deployment settings, you can reboot the instance and it usually solve the problem.